# QML ProgressBar's vertical orientation does not fill to top at 100%

Tags: qml

Inside QML `MainWindow`, I have `Slider` and `ProgressBar`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true

    width: Screen.width/2
    height: Screen.height/2

    opacity: 1.00

    color: "black"

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Slider
        {
            id: ueSlider

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.margins: 8
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

            activeFocusOnPress: false
            tickmarksEnabled: false

            minimumValue: 0
            maximumValue: 100
            stepSize: 1

            orientation: Qt.Vertical

            onValueChanged:
            {
                ueProgressBar.value=value;
            }   // onValueChanged
        }   // Slider

        ProgressBar
        {
            id: ueProgressBar

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.margins: 8
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter

            orientation: Qt.Vertical

            indeterminate: false

            onValueChanged:
            {
                print("ProgressBar value: "+value);
            }   // onValueChanged

            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                minimumValue=ueSlider.minimumValue;
                maximumValue=ueSlider.maximumValue;
                value=ueSlider.value;
            }   // Component.onCompleted
        }   // ProgressBar
    }   // RowLayout
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

Now, the `ProgressBar` is "connected" to `Slider` - when I change value of `Slider`, the `ProgressBar`'s `value` changes. If I change `ProgressBar`'s `orientation` to `Qt.Horizontal`, everything works fine, but if I change its `orienation` to `Qt.Vertical`, run example and push `Slider` to top (to its `maximumValue`), the `ProgressBar` does not go to `100%`:
[image: ProgressBar problem]
Why the hell?!

Comment: Could it be due to gravity? :-)

Comment: No, @skypjack that happens because of comments on closing brackets. ;-) But seriously,I  I've tested it on Linux KDE and Windows 7 and all works as expected. Try to play with  `ProgressBar.maximumValue` and `ProgressBar.minimumValue`. By default `ProgressBar.maximumValue` is 1 and not 100

Comment: @folibis `ProgressBar.maximumValue` is set at `Component.onCompleted`!

Comment: @KernelPanic You have no guarantees that at the time of `onCompleted` for the progress bar, your slider is actually completed too. Try moving those operations into the `onCompleted` of the parent component.